Replacing values in a df using a dictionary nested in a list of dataframes - R
I'm trying to use a dictionary to replace values in a dataframe using a nested list of dataframes. I have a large df with coded columns that I'd like to decode with the text values.
Here's a sample of the data:
reprex_dat <- structure(list(glucose_Glucose_bloodvalue = c(8.45, NA, 8.95, 
8.97, 6.14, NA, 5.2, 6.46, 6.23, NA), glucose_Glucose_valueUnits = c("2", 
NA, "1", "1", "1", NA, "1", "1", "1", NA), calcium_Calcium_bloodvalue = c(1.18, 
NA, 1.14, 2.33, 1.21, NA, 2.38, 2.44, 1.19, NA), calcium_Calcium_valueUnits = c("1", 
NA, "1", "1", "1", NA, "1", "1", "1", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

reprex_headers <- structure(list(`Glucose - Glucose - Units` = c("0=mg/dL, 1=mmol/L, 2=mEq/L, 3=g/dL, 4=g/L, 5=Other, 6=mmol", 
"glucose_Glucose_valueUnits"), `Calcium - Calcium - Units` = c("0=mg/dL, 1=mmol/L, 2=µmol/L, 3=mg/100mL, 4=mg%, 5=mg/L, 6=µg/mL, 7=Other, 8=mEq/L", 
"calcium_Calcium_valueUnits")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Here's what it looks like:


the "headers" decodes the "Units" values corresponding to the "bloodvalue" numbers and so I generate a list of dataframes where each row of an element in a list gives me a key pair
units_vec <- reprex_headers[1,] |> select(ends_with("Units"))
units_res <- vector(mode='list', length=ncol(units_vec))

# Split at comma, unlist, split at equal, unlist, covert to data frame then transpose 
for (i in seq_along(1:length(units_res))) {
  units_res[[i]] <- t(data.frame(str_split(unlist(str_split(units_vec[i], ", ")), "="), row.names = c("values","units")))
  rownames(units_res[[i]]) <- NULL
}
names(units_res) <- reprex_headers[2,] |> select(ends_with("Units"))


> units_res[[1]]
     values units   
[1,] "0"    "mg/dL" 
[2,] "1"    "mmol/L"
[3,] "2"    "mEq/L" 
[4,] "3"    "g/dL"  
[5,] "4"    "g/L"   
[6,] "5"    "Other" 
[7,] "6"    "mmol"  

and as such, I can use match to replace those values like this:
units_res[[1]][, "units"][match(reprex_dat$glucose_Glucose_valueUnits, units_res[[1]][, "values"])]

 [1] "mEq/L"  NA       "mmol/L" "mmol/L" "mmol/L" NA       "mmol/L" "mmol/L" "mmol/L" NA    

But here is where I get stuck. I try to integrate match into a loop and can't figure out where I'm failing.
for (i in seq_along(1:length(names(units_res)))) {
  j <- names(units_res)[i]
  for (k in seq_along(1:nrow(units_res[[i]])))
    
  reprex_dat[k,j] <- units_res[[i]][, "units"][match(reprex_dat[k,j], units_res[[i]][, "values"])]
}

Which yields this which is close but not perfect:


You could use mapply
reprex_dat[,c(2,4)] <- mapply(\(x,y) y[,"units"][match(x, y[,"values"])], 
                              x=reprex_dat[,c(2,4)], 
                              y=units_res)
reprex_dat[,c(2,4)]


# A tibble: 10 × 2
   glucose_Glucose_valueUnits calcium_Calcium_valueUnits
   <chr>                      <chr>                     
 1 mEq/L                      mmol/L                    
 2 NA                         NA                        
 3 mmol/L                     mmol/L                    
 4 mmol/L                     mmol/L                    
 5 mmol/L                     mmol/L                    
 6 NA                         NA                        
 7 mmol/L                     mmol/L                    
 8 mmol/L                     mmol/L                    
 9 mmol/L                     mmol/L                    
10 NA                         NA 


Fixed the bad for-loop
for (i in seq_along(1:length(names(units_res)))) {
  j <- names(units_res)[i]
  for (k in seq_along(1:nrow(reprex_dat[,j])))
    
  reprex_dat[k,j] <- units_res[[i]][, "units"][match(reprex_dat[k,j], units_res[[i]][, "values"])]
}

This does beg the question, is there a cleaner way?
